# Show that $\left | \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k - \sum_{m+1}^{n}a_k \right| \leq \max|a_k|$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for each finite real number sequence $(a_k)$, there is exists a $m\leq n$ such that $\left | \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k - \sum_{m+1}^{n}a_k \right| \leq  \max|a_k|$.

Does it use contradiction to prove it? So there is exist finite sequence such that no $m$ is hold that inequality. Please give me a clue.

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le m\le n$, let $S_m:=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k-\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k$. 
If $S_m=0$ for some $m$, we are done.
Hence assume $S_m\ne 0$ for all $m$.
As $S_n=-S_0$, there are $m$ such that $S_m$ is positive and others such that $S_m$ is negative. Hence there exists $m>0$ such that $S_{m-1}$ and $S_{m}$ have opposite sign. But $S_{m}-S_{m-1}=2a_m$ (or equivalently $(S_m-a_m)+(-S_m-a_m)=0$).
If $S_m>0>S_{m-1}$ then $a_m>0$ and at least one of $S_m- a_m$, $-S_m- a_m$ must be nonnegative, i.e., $|S_m|\le |a_m|$ or $|S_{m-1}|\le |a_m|$.
Similarly, if $S_m<0<S_{m-1}$ then $a_m<0$ and at least one of $S_m- a_m$, $-S_m- a_m$ must be nonpositive, i.e., $|S_m|\le |a_m|$ or $|S_{m-1}|\le |a_m|$, again.

Comment: "As $S_n=-S_0$, there are $m$ such that $S_m$ is positive and others such that $S_m$ is negative". Why ? I don't understand it